# qt button added on menu bar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qvboxlayout

I'm trying to add buttons to a vertical layout in QT.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    mRootLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    setLayout(mRootLayout);

    mRootLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button1", this));
    mRootLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button2", this));

}
```

I have 2 problems
1. The buttons are created on top of the menu bar
2. The buttons are not one under the other one.

I'm using a QVBoxLayout.

[image]

Comment: The parent of layout must be ui's central widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think code must be change to:

```
mRootLayout = new QVBoxLayout(ui->centralWidget);
mRootLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button1", this));
mRootLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button2", this));
```

It's not necessary do `setLayout()`.